# How to draw line slowly in Android?

Tags: android, line, android-canvas, draw

I am trying to draw points to android canvas slowly. I want to use canvas.drawline function however drawing one point to another i want to have small delay. Can you help me please?

Comment: Delays in Android are usually best accomplished with a Handler.  Create a Runnable that draws a small segment of your line and re-posts itself with a delay until the line is complete.

Comment: can you share example code please. I tried to use asynctask and timer however after freezing screen final result (line) was drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the general pattern:

```
// PSEUDOCODE
// in a class created in a Looper thread, e.g., the main thread
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

static class DrawTask implements Runnable {
    // final fields for start point, end point, number of segments, interval, etc.
    // mutable field for progress

    // constructor with appropriate params

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // draw the current line segment
        if(!finished) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, interval);
        }
    }
}

// in some draw method
handler.post(new DrawTask(...));
```

You might want to hang onto a reference to the DrawTask so you can cancel it with `Handler#removeCallbacks(...)` in case it's still running when your activity is paused.

Comment: Thank you for help. I handle this by using async task and timer.